# ¿Como puedo mostrar los valores de varios checkbox en un pdf (doompdf) en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

Ocupo ayuda, necesito mostrar la info de varios checkbox en una vista pdf, pero no los puedo leer con el foreach, tengo una teoria de que es porque son mas de 1 linea de datos

//Este es mi codigo de la ruta

```
route::get('/pdfrequi', function (Request $request) {
    $impresiones = $request->all();
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('requisiciones.pdfrequi',compact('impresiones'));
    return $pdf->stream();

})->name('pdfrequi');
```

//Este es el foreach de la tabla donde estan los checkbox

```
@foreach($mostrar as $item)
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="datos[]" value="{{$item}}">  //Este es el checkbox
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <div style="width: -moz-max-content;width: max-content;">
                        <a href="{{route('verrequi',$item)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                        <form action="{{route('bajarequi',$item)}}" method="post" class="d-inline">
                          @csrf
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="button"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{$item->Requisicion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Cantidad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Unidad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->OT}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Cliente}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->OC}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Proyecto}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Fecha}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Solicito}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->Familia}}</td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
```

//Este es como intento mostrarlo en el pdf

```
   @foreach($impresiones as $item)
      <td>{{$item->Cantidad}}</td>
      <td>{{$item->Unidad}}</td>
      <td>{{$item->Descripcion}}</td>
      <td>{{$item->OT}}</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
    @endforeach
```

//Este es el error

```
 Trying to get property 'Cantidad' of non-object (View: C:\Users\Sistemas\Desktop\AEME\AEME_App\resources\views\requisiciones\pdfrequi.blade.php)
```

//dd($impresiones)

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "pWqk8CDHua5dGyN2FKv9sxse7amsimuxVVC8whhM"
  "dtBasicExample_length" => "10"
  "datos" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "{"id":1,"Requisicion":2,"Cantidad":2,"Unidad":"a","Descripcion":"a","OT":"a","Cliente":"a","OC":"a","Proyecto":"a","Fecha":"2020-09-10","Solicito":"a","Familia" ▶"
    1 => "{"id":2,"Requisicion":3,"Cantidad":10,"Unidad":"Caja","Descripcion":"aasddddddddddfsdfasdfadsfasdfasdfsadfasdfsdafsadf","OT":"789456","Cliente":"Vitro","OC":"as ▶"
  ]
]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes hacerl un `dd()` a `$impresiones ` y decirnos que resultado obtienes?

Comment: Ya esta el resultado en la pregunta amigo

Comment: Los _checkbox_ no son parte del formulario, de hecho, generas un formulario por cada elemento, pero solo incluyes `@csrf` y un botón de envío.

Comment: si son parte de un formulario, solamente no esta incluido en la parte del codigo porque no es tan importante ponerlo, te comento amigo, todo jala hasta que llego a la parte importante del codigo que es lo de arriba con ese error

Comment: Bueno, dos cosas: Parece que tienes formularios anidados, el principal y los que generas para eliminar cada elemento; generalmente da problemas al hacer _submit_. De acuerdo al resultado que pusiste, parece que debes recorrer `$impresiones['datos']` para acceder a cada elemento.